# How to wake up from Hibernation at a given day/time?

Tags: c#, windows

I need to wake up a hibernated laptop at a given time every day.

Should I use pinvoke? If yes? which one? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wake the computer up from sleep, I'm not sure about hibernate. [This example](http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/wake-up-from-sleep-createwaitabletimer-in-c.aspx) shows you how to do it. In short you use these two imports:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern SafeWaitHandle CreateWaitableTimer(IntPtr lpTimerAttributes, bool bManualReset, string lpTimerName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWaitableTimer(SafeWaitHandle hTimer, [In] ref long pDueTime, int lPeriod, IntPtr pfnCompletionRoutine, IntPtr lpArgToCompletionRoutine, bool fResume);
```

I've only tested it on Windows Vista and 7, these may not be available on XP.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's VB and not C#, but take a look at [this example](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=396217), it does require that your motherboard meets certain requirements.